# Why does function output the wrong value?

Tags: c#, io

The `Function` below i wrote to check whether a `File/Directory` Path exists or not, alongside there's the `RecentPath` which retrieves the last path that has been checked by the `Function`.

```
    private static String IRecentPath;
    public static String RecentPath
    {
        get
        {
            return IRecentPath;
        }
    }

    public static Boolean Exists(String Path, Int32 PathType = 0)
    {
        return Exist(Path, PathType);
    }

    internal static Boolean Exist(String Path, Int32 PathType = 0)
    {
        Boolean Report = false;
        switch (PathType)
        {
            case 0:
                Report = (Directory.Exists(Path) || File.Exists(Path));
                IRecentPath = Path;
                break;
            case 1:
                String MPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                Report = (Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(MPath, Path)) || File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(MPath, Path)));
                IRecentPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(MPath, Path);
                break;
            case 2:
                String LPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                Report = (Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(LPath, Path)) || File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(LPath, Path)));
                IRecentPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(LPath, Path);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return Report;
    }
```

The problem is that `RecentPath` always retrieves the path that has been set while calling the function and not the final path.

Example:

Let's say that i needed to check if `/user` directory exists in `myDocument` and then get the last recent path that has been checked, so:

```
Path.Exists("/user", 2);
MessageBox.Show(Path.RecentPath);
```

The output should be `C:\Users\Hossam\Documents\user\` but instead it's just `/user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slash (`/`) at the beginning of your input string apparently interferes with the `Path.Combine()`. Try this:

```
Path.Exists("user", 2);
MessageBox.Show(Path.RecentPath);
```

Output: `C:\Users\Hossam\Documents\user`

Comment: "interferes" might not be a correct word for this. This is basically how IO.Path.Combine works - it sees that second argument starts with separator, apparently assumes that it is already at the root, and just outputs second path. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for some details.

Comment: @Andrei I know it should and that's why it never came to my mind that that was the problem, but somehow when i used just `"user"` it worked fine!!?

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks for pointing that out. The slash prevents the OP's intended behavior, but is perfectly in line with Path.Combine's defined behavior. "If path2 contains an absolute path, this method returns path2."

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you pass a string that begins with the forward slash.
In Windows systems this is the  [AltDirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx)

In the [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) docs you can read this remark

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start
>   with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a
>   concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator
>   character. **If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.**

Now looking at the source code of Path.Combine you could see

```
.....
if (IsPathRooted(path2))
{
    return path2;
}
....
```

and of course IsPathRooted contains

```
.....
if (path[0] == AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
{
    return true;
}
.....
```